# Script Compliation Errors on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

With Using Android Studio,first,you can create project so that you can choose language.I can choose     configuration language whose named is Kotlin DSL,package named is build.gradle.kts.I met up with problems.
Configuration problems,Synchronization problems.Build options are perfomed to have sufficient problem that I could observe.                                                                                                         Problem Details:Unsolved Reference:VERSION_1_8:,Script Compilation Errors

```
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.keremaltun.myapplication"
        minSdk = 18
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

Comment: Kotlin Gradle plugin must be at least version 1.5.0 in order to support the VERSION_1_8 property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this (with `JavaVersion.` prefix):

```
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
```